# Rails: Automatically add username to new post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, posts

In my posts controller, I am using the following to see the user ID's of different posts made by students:

```
def new
  @post = current_user.posts.build
end
```

This is very useful. However, it would be more useful if I can see their names and usernames too. Right now I am making students manually type in their name.

How can you make new posts automatically grab the logged in user's username and name?

Comment: But why would a post need to save the user's `username` and `name` in the first place? A post belongs to a user, so you can do `@post.user.name` to get the name of the user. A post object only needs to save `user_id`, and then using associations, you can get all the attributes of the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the user's `username` and `name` associated with the `@post`, you can do:

```rb
username = @post.user.username
name     = @post.user.name
```

You should always go and ask the `user` of `@post` for the attributes that belong to the user.

Comment: Thank you. For posterity: it didn't display correctly unless I used <%= post.user.username unless post.user.blank? %>

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the delegate method/Delegation pattern [described more here](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/). API description is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :username, :name, :to => :user
end
```

Then you can call: `@post.username` and that will return the username of the user.

Comment: This is also known as [`law of demeter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using Devise. So in the `_form.html.erb`you can show the username like this...First, let's say that each **User** `has_one` :**Profile** `(:username, :first_name, :last_name)`

so that
user.rb

```
has_one :profile
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

In your Post form you could do 
`_form.html.erb`

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %> : <%= current_user.profile.username %>
    or (if you define a method in your Model that will return your first_name and last_name)
    <%= f.label :full_name %> : <%= current_user.profile.first_and_last_name %>
    or
    <%= f.label :full_name %> : <%= current_user.profile.first_name %>  &nbsp; <%= current_user.profile.last_name %> 
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you have assumed quite a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A `post` *created* with the code you've posted will automatically have the `user`'s name available through the `.user` associative method:

```
@post = Post.find x
@post.user.name #-> "name" of associated "user" model
```

---

Since you've only posted a `new` method, and have asked the proceeding question, I'll write some code for you:

> Right now I am making students manually type in their name

Why do students have to type their name anyway?

The whole point of [`ActiveRecord`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) (and relational databases) is to give access to associative data; storing `user` details (`name` etc) in the `users` table, and having it accessible through `posts`.

This is what you'd do with your `posts` controller:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = current_user.posts.new
   end

   def create
      @post = current_user.posts.new post_params
      @post.save
   end

   def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
      @username = @post.user.name
   end
end
```

This will automatically set the `user_id` [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for your new `post`, which *should* allow you to call the user's name using `@post.user.name`

--

If you wanted to refactor this, to avoid the [**`law of demeter`**](http://samurails.com/tutorial/rails-delegate-dont-break-the-law-of-demeter/), you'll want to use the `delegate` method as `Dewyze` recommended:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true #-> post.user_name
end
```

`Dewyze`'s answer is slightly wrong in that his would yield `@post.name` - you need the `prefix` if you wanted to identify the record by its model.

Comment: To clarify, the question also requested the username in addition to the name, so prefix would not be necessary. If you had prefix true, it would end up being `@post.user_username` and `@post.user_name`. I was referring to the username one, although pointing out prefix is useful.

Comment: Sorry about that - your code would still create `@post.name` though ;)